# Informatica insert update code with flag 'N' , 'U', how to update

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

If profile comes with N flag need to insert to profile_id, if comes U flag update to profile_temp. Some times user comes with N flag as well for update which needs to be updated to profile_ temp only. when it already loaded to profile I'd and later came after some profile has been assigned with N flag but this time it came for update.  How do I do it in mapping in infa?

Comment: and what did you do so far?
please share with us some code snippet 
 please take a moment and read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask about how to asking questions also read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example about how to ask a good question with minimum requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Pls use expression transformation and then update strategies.

1. First of all use a expression to create a flag.

```
flag_insert_update = 
IIF ( user_flag = 'N', 'INS_PROFILE',
  IIF ( user_flag = 'UPDATE', 'UPD_PROFILE_TEMP',
    IIF (user_flag = 'n','UPD_PROFILE_TEMP'
 ))) -- You can calculate as per your logic.
```

2. Use a router to split data between profile and profile_temp.

```
group 1 = flag_insert_update = 'INS_PROFILE'
group 2 = flag_insert_update <> 'INS_PROFILE'
```

3. Then use multiple update strategies. one linked to PROFILE table, another linked to PROFILE_TEMP table.

update strategy logic for PROFILE  table -

```
IIF(flag_insert_update ='INS_PROFILE', 'DD_INSERT' ) -- pls note else condition is null.
```

update strategy logic for PROFILE_TEMP  table -

```
IIF(flag_insert_update ='UPD_PROFILE_TEMP', 'DD_UPDATE' ) -- pls note else condition is null.
```

4. Then link update strategies to their corresponding target.

Whole mapping should look like this.

```
                              |-UPD_PROFILE --> TGT_PROFILE
EXP_FLAG_INS_UPD -RTR_SPLIT ->|-UPD_PROFILE_TEMP --> TGT_PROFILE_TEMP
```

Comment: Sorry the typo error the flag for new user only 'N' not 'n' for this comes as insert as new user and also update sometimes .with same N flag.